# Complex line integral $\sinh(z)$ over piecewise smooth line

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, line-integrals

I have to calculate the following integral (1) by definition and (2) by using the primitive:

$\int_\alpha{\sinh(z)dz}$

where $\alpha$ is the line from $0$ to $\pi$ and from $\pi$ to $\pi + i\pi$.

I am kind of familiar with the Cauchy integral theorem, but not sure how/if I have to use it here.

I wanted to write $\alpha$ as: $\alpha: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, and maybe splitting it up for the two lines? Then perhaps use:

$\int_\alpha{f(z)dz} = \int_a ^b f(\alpha(t))\alpha'(t)dt$.

Not sure if this is useful, so a little help is appreciated.

Comment: This is a line segment so the integral theorem doesn't apply here. You'll need to write this as two integrals over both segments and use techniques from Calculus III.

Answer (score 0):

On the line from 0 to $\pi$, we can write z= x so that the integral becomes $\int_0^\pi \frac{e^x- e^{-x}}{2}dx$ which is easy to integrate.  On the line from $\pi$ to $\pi+ i\pi$ we can write $z= \pi+ ix$ so that the integral becomes $\int_0^\pi e^{\pi+ ix}- e^{-\pi-ix}{2} i dx=  e^\pi\frac{i}{2}\int_0^{\pi} e^{ix}dx+ \frac{i}{2}e^{-\pi}\int_0^\pi e^{-ix}dx$

Comment: Don't you mean for the integral $z = \pi + ix$, divided by 2 instead of multiplied by 2? And is the $i$ coming from the $z = \pi + ix$? And why is there a + instead of a - in the final integral?